# English translation of Riemann's complete works

Tags: math-history, reference-works

Browsing in the library I came across with the mathematical (and some philosophical) papers of Riemann, collected by Weber and Dedekind in the original German (although published by Dover). But apparently there's no English translation reported in internet, even for the most influential papers like the November 1859 report on the Zeta function, and in such a volume some of Riemann's correspondence with mathematicians in other languages are transcribed in the respective original (for example a letter in Italian to Betti). Since the volume is relative thin and certainly highly relevant I wonder if there exists an English translation. (By the way, apparently his complete correspondence has never been fully collected).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an English translation of the [collected papers of Riemann](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0974042730), in $2004$. It says "This is the first English translation of the collected papers of Bernhard Riemann (1826-1866), one of the greatest mathematicians of all time. Riemann surfaces, Riemannian geometry and the Riemann zeta function are fundamental concepts of modern mathematics." And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Though it does not address your question, [On the Number of Prime Numbers less than
a Given Quantity](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf) is an excellent translation of his [Riemann's 1859 Manuscript](https://www.claymath.org/publications/riemanns-1859-manuscript).

This might be useful to others.